# JSON Decoding using decodable protocol with Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I'm decoding a music API using the decodable protocol.

The easy stuff is working well, and i'm able to get the things with a key, however there is a genre array inside the results array which have no keys.

Part of the JSON:

```
"results": [{
    "country": "Europe",
    "year": "2017",
    "format": ["Vinyl", "LP", "Album", "Mispress"],
    "label": ["Parkwood Entertainment", "Columbia", "Sony Music", "Sony Music Entertainment", "Sony Music Entertainment International Services GmbH", "Columbia Records", "Columbia Records", "Parkwood Entertainment LLC", "Parkwood Entertainment LLC", "Celebrate Records GmbH", "Celebrate Records GmbH"],
    "type": "release",
    "genre": ["Electronic", "Rock", "Funk / Soul", "Pop"],
    "style": ["Rhythm & Blues", "Soul", "Neo Soul", "Electro", "Punk"],
    "id": 10869960,
```

my model in xcode: Here I don't know what I have to define if I don't have the key

```
    struct Results:Codable {
    
    var catno:String?
    var country:String?
    var id:Int?
    var master_id:Int?
    var thumb:String?
    var title:String?
    var genre:[Genre]?
    var type:String?
    var uri:String?
    var year:String?
    
}

struct Genre:Codable {
    
}
```

My function that I use to retrieve the data from the API

```
private func getRecords(_ searchMethod:String, searchString:String) {
    // Check the requested search method and make api call with searchString
    var urlString:String = ""
    var resultsArray = [Results]()
    
    if searchMethod == "barcode" {
        urlString = DiscogsAPI.barcode + searchString + DiscogsAPI.token
    }
    else if searchMethod == "title" {
        urlString = DiscogsAPI.title + searchString + DiscogsAPI.token
    }
    
    // Session setup and api call
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    
    guard url != nil else {
        return
    }
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        // Peform datatask and handle data
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let resultsData = try decoder.decode(Record.self, from: data!)
                let genreData = try decoder.decode(Genre.self, from: data!)
                
                resultsArray = resultsData.results!
                print(resultsArray[0].genre)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegate?.discogsResult(resultsArray)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("error getting data")
            }
            
        }
        else {
            print("data of error nil")
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: `format`, `genre`, `style` and `label` is `[String]` and decoding two different types from the same data is pretty pointless. One of them will definitely throw an error. And you don't know what error because you `print` a meaningless literal string.

Comment: I only want the genre, don't need the rest. the print statements was just for testing so is the let genreData = try etc

Comment: You have to decode JSON always from the top. Skipping intermediate objects is not possible

Comment: Your suggestion of changing the genre:[Genre] to genre:[String] works, thanks.

And what do you mean that I cannot skip parts? It should only assign the parts in the struct which I need which works great.

Comment: I mean you cannot decode `Genre.self` if it's not the root object.

Comment: Aah yes, thanks for the help.